# Where can I find the source code for /bin/ip?

Tags: source

I've been using the command `/bin/ip`:

```
ip addr add 10.10.10.0 dev eth0
```

I would like to see the source code of how the `ip` command works. Is it available?

Comment: Are you looking for sources matching the distribution you are using? If so, you should mention which distribution you are using.

Comment: We can help you better if you provide the Version and Distribution you are using and asking about.

Comment: The `ip` utility is part of the iproute2 suite.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for the source (code) of well-known software is most likely not useful for other U&L users.

Comment: @countermode It may be "well-known" to experts, but not to me and the other 4 who voted up..  Shouldn't questions that may be obvious to some still be left open for us less-enlightened individuals?

Comment: It does not require advanced searches on bing/google to find out where `ip` comes from (admitted, you have to be more careful with the query). U&L is a knowledge base for solving problems and in this sense I still claim that neither the question nor the answers to it contribute to U&L. This has nothing to do with enlightened or not enlightened, this has to do with the concept of U&L. You may want to have a look at http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html, especially the Section "Before You Ask" (inspired by Jeff Schaller here on U&L).

Comment: 1000 views on this question. I guess this wasn't "off-topic" after all.

Comment: It is not off topic, today is 2022 and I am looking for this!

Comment: @countermode I'm very glad I found this. Very much on topic!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `ip` program is part of the `iproute2` software package, and can be downloaded from [www.kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/net/iproute2/). N.b. Unlike the old `ipconfig` program, which uses `ioctls` to do its job, the `iproute2` utilities use [Netlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink) sockets to communicate with the kernel. It helps understanding how the `ip` program works if you are familiarised with Netlink sockets.